# USSD message sending through AT command with a huawei modem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, gsm, modem, ussd

I'm trying to send ussd messages with a huawei modem through AT Command.
Here is my function which writes At command into serial port.

for sms ,im trying the following and its working and i can den sms.

```
 string recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT", 300, "No phone connected");
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
            String command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + PhoneNo + "\"";
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");         
            command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds
            if (recievedData.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
            {
                isSend = true;
            }
            else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                isSend = false;
            }
```

but for ussd messages,while im trying the following,

```
  string recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT", 300, "No phone connected");
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
            String command = "AT+CUSD=1,*566#";
            recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 3000, "Failed to send ussd");
            Console.WriteLine("received data : " +recievedData);
          //  command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
          //  recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds
            if (recievedData.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
            {
                isSend = true;
            }
            else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                isSend = false;
            }
```

first two exec command returns ok,but the third exec command returns error.

USSD code is working from providers mobile partner application,

what sets of AT command do i need to send to handle ussd application properly?